# Modal Window containing ui-view.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it posible to use Angular UI Router inside of a modal window? I want to create a multi step form that will walk the user through a three step process to fill out profile info. I was thinking this would not be so tuff. My idea was to have a modal like so:

```
<div id="custom-modal">
  <div id="overlay">
      <a href ng-click="close()">Close</a>
      <div class="content">

        <div ui-view></div>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My intent was to set up a route for each step of the process containing its own template. Unfortunately I have not been able to find a way to do this. Is there a way to do this? Can you point me to any examples? Any assistance would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: did you check   

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router

Comment: I have done that before, you don't need to add every modal in the Routes. You just need your controller and a view, you can add into that view a button or a condition to display the first modal. In that modal you can show part of the form to fill up the info of the user with a continue button that will close that modal, assign the data you have and then open the next modal to fill the next data and so on until you get to the last modal and the last button will save/validate all the data or send it to an API. If you need a more detail example let me know and i can help you with one.

Comment: That looks like the exact thing Im looking for.

Comment: That sounds like a much better approach. Yes I would truly appreciate more details. I can't quiet wrap my mind around the description. Would you still use separate templates for each modal?

Answer (score 0):

ui-router, you set the routes like this.

you still use your ui-view, but in your app.js you set up the $stateProvider

```
Router.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function Router($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $stateProvider
    .state('portfolio', {
      url: '/', 
      templateUrl: 'portfolio.html'
    })
    .state('login',{
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .state('feed',{
      url: '/feed',
      templateUrl: 'feed.html'
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```